# How to add a legend to ngb-timepicker fieldset?

Tags: html, angular, legend, timepicker

I need to add a  tag to the ngb-timepicker's fieldset however, it seems like there is no way to do it. Anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap prefix to append it to timepicker input.

[image]

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-timepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './timepicker-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdTimepickerBasic implements AfterViewInit {
  
  @ViewChild('timePicker') picker: ElementRef;
  time = { hour: 13, minute: 30 };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let minuteInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[aria-label="Minutes"]');
    var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    myDiv.style.display = 'flex';
    myDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">mm</span>
    </div>
  </div>`;
    minuteInput[0].parentNode.insertBefore(myDiv, minuteInput[0]);
    myDiv.insertBefore(minuteInput[0], myDiv.children[0]);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyawz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftimepicker-basic.ts